# Collision Detection algorithms with early Collision exit

Tags: collision-detection

I'm using collision detection in Monte Carlo simulations and at the moment I'm using GJK which is quite fast. I can't help to think it could be done even faster though. In the simulations, about 70% of the time GJK is run, it detects a collision. Thus collisions are more than non-collisions in my case. Most collision detection algorithms I know have an early non-collision exit test.

Are there any collision detection algorithms that have an early collision detect instead of non-collision and could be potentially faster than GJK in case of collision?

Answer (score 1):

I think this case is unusual because generally the non collision case is more common and because the user of the collision detection test needs additional information when a hit is reported (contact point, normal, parametric sweep amount) and that wouldn't be available in the early out case.

That said you could easily imagine doing a faster test with primitives that are inwardly conservative (i.e. sphere vs. sphere where each sphere is completely contained inside its respective GJK primitive)